# Php remove BR-tag

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove the `<br />` in output from database but this isn't really working out for me. My code starts with `nl2br`, which produces `<br />`. But I will allow my users to edit the texts and I would love to make sure that it line breaks are allowed in editing too.

But in my `<textarea>` it prints out the `<br />` tag. All I want is a line break.

```
echo nl2br(preg_replace("/<br\W*?\/>/", "", $row["content"]));
```

Comment: Make that a answer and you will get a check mark :)

Comment: Your regex is correct at least

Comment: @sfsefsf33fs3fs3fs You should consider using an editor.  Markitup is good for editing code, summernote is a decent WYSIWYG, and tinymce is a full featured (if bloated) WYSIWYG.  Basically they allow you to edit with breaks, but save in new lines.

Comment: Answer added, also an additional note about possible improvement to your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run the `nl2br` that is outputting `br`s. Also use `\n` in the replace value so you get new lines.

```
echo preg_replace("/<br\W*?\/>/", "\n", $row["content"]);
```

You also might want to use `\h` or `\s` instead of `\W`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, there is two forms that you would like to use, when you want to display the text entered in a textarea, then you need the nl2br, which inserts br tags into the text. You may also want to save the contents to a database this way.

When you want to load the text back to a textarea, then depending on how you saved the text:

- if it is saved with newlines: do nothing with the text just load it into the textarea
- if it is saved with br tags: you need the preg_replace(...) part of your code with '\n' as the replacement (`preg_replace("/<br\W*?\/>/", "\n", $row["content"]);`).